# Strange horizontal scrolling issue with my bootstrap page

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been working on a Bootstrap page and I'm getting a horizontal scrolling issue. Does anyone out there know why? My page can be seen here http://jnoweb.com/projects/bootstrap-test/ and here's my CSS:

```
@media (min-width: 1400px) and (max-width: 1440px){
            body {
                background:#ffffff; 
            }
            .container-fluid {
                max-width:1440px !important;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
            .maxWidth {
                max-width:1440px !important;
            }
            .background {
                background:#f4f4f4;
                width: 1440px;
                height: 75em;
                display: block;
                position: absolute;
                top:0;
                left:0;
            }
            .container {
                background:#ffffff !important;
                width: 1400px;
                padding-right: 15px;
                padding-left: 15px;
                margin-right: auto;
                margin-left: auto;
            }
            /* Style for "logo" */
            .logo {
                padding-left: 116px; 
                padding-top: 30px;
            }
            /* Style for "SHELL PRIV" */
            .tagline {
                color: #d42e12;
                font-family: "Futura PT";
                font-size: 1.5em;
                font-weight: 700;
                line-height: .6em;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                position: relative;
                top: 50px;
                left: 505px;
            }
            .background-retusche {
                background: url('../images/background1.jpg') no-repeat;
                width: 1400px;
                height: 639px;
                margin: 0 0 0 -15px;
                padding: 0;
            }
            .retusche {height: 639px;margin-left:-15px;padding:0;}
            .bosom-none {
                margin-right: 15px; // Removes the right gap
                margin-left: 15px;  // Removes the left gap
            }
            .base-white {
                /* Style for "base white" */
                width: 585px;
                height: 147px;
                border-radius: 8px;
                background-color: #ffffff;
                margin-top: 49px;
                margin-left: 115px;
            }
            h1.power-ohne {
                /* Style for "Power ohne" */
                color: #f18713;
                font-family: "Roboto Condensed";
                font-size: 50px;
                font-weight: 400;
                line-height: 50px;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
            .iphone {
                margin:0; 
                padding:0; 
                position: absolute; 
                left:-15px; 
                top: 230px;
            }
            /* Style for "wohnzimmer" */
            .wohnzimmer {
                width: 242px;
                height: 137px;
                position: absolute;
                top: 62px;
                left: 75px;
            }
            /* Style for "200% apple" */
            .apple {
                width: 128px;
                height: 40px;
                margin:0; 
                padding:0; 
                position: absolute; 
                left: 115px; 
                top: 559px;
            }
            /* Style for "200% googl" */
            .googl {
                width: 128px;
                height: 40px;
                margin:0; 
                padding:0; 
                position: absolute; 
                left: 253px; 
                top: 559px;
            }
            /* Style for "cam" */
            .cam {
                width: 195px;
                height: 287px;
                margin:0; 
                padding:0; 
                position: absolute; 
                left: 413px; 
                top: 369px;
                z-index: 10;
            }
            .circle {
                width: 222px;
                height: 222px;
                background: #e20613;
                border-radius: 50%;
                position: absolute; 
                left: 586px; 
                top: 302px;
            }
            /* Style for "Strom inkl" */
            h2.strom-inkl {
                color: #ffffff;
                font-family: "Roboto Condensed";
                font-weight: 700;
                padding: 10px 15px;
            }
            ul {
                display: block;
                margin-left: -3.5em;
                top: 1em;
                margin-top: -30px;
                position: relative;
                list-style: none;
            }
            li {padding: 0px 0px;}
            .light{
                -webkit-text-stroke: 5px #e20613;
                color: white;
                vertical-align:sub;
            }
            .smartfrog {font-size:1em; color:white;font-family: "Roboto Condensed" !important;font-size: 18px;font-weight: 700; }
            .panel-default > .panel-heading {
                  color: #333;
                  background-color: #f7d117;
                  border-color: #ddd;
                  text-align: center;
            }
            h2.panel-title {
                font-size: 30px;
                color: #d42e12;
                font-family: "Roboto Condensed";
                font-weight: 700;
                height: 56px;
                line-height: 58px;
            }
            .panel-right {
                width:413px;
                position: absolute;
                right:115px;
                top:49px;
                height:520px;
            }
            .gap-top {
              margin-top: 28px; 
            }
            .gap-left {
             margin-left: 14px;
            }
            .sich-light {
                -webkit-text-stroke: 7px white;
                color: #e20613;
                vertical-align: sub;
            }
            .sich {
                font-size:2em !important; 
                color: black; 
                font-family: "Roboto Condensed" !important;
                font-size: 18px;
                font-weight: 400; 
            }
            ul.panel-list {
                display: block;
                width:30em;
                margin-left: -1.8em;
                margin-top: .2em;
            }
            /* Style for "Vektor-Sma" */
            .shell {
                text-align:right; 
                margin:0; 
                padding:.7em 0 .7em;
            }
            .shell-red {
                color: #e20613 !important;
            }
            .shell-red-background {
                background-color: #e20613 !important;
                color: #ffffff;
            }
            /* Style for "Rechteck 2" */
            .rechteck2 {
                margin-top: -1px;
                height: 180px; 
                background-color: #f7d117;
            }
            /* Style for form */
            h2 {
                display:inline-block;
            }
            .form-group button {
                padding: 10em 0;
                margin: 0;
            }
            form {
                padding: 6em 0;
                width: 750px;
                margin: 0 auto;
                background-color: #f7d117;
            }
            .form-none {
                margin-right: -15px; // Removes the right gap
                margin-left: -15px;  // Removes the left gap
            }
            .footer-links {
                padding-top:2em;
                padding-bottom:2em;
                padding-right: 19em;
                padding-left: 19em;
                margin-right: auto;
                margin-left: auto;
                line-height: 30px;
                color: #646464;
                text-align: center;
                font-size: 1em;
            }
            .siteinfo {
                /* Style for "Shell Priv" */
                text-align: center;
                padding: 3em 0;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
                color: #414141;
                font-family: "Roboto Condensed";
                font-size: 13px;
                font-weight: 400;
                line-height: 18px;
            }
            .siteinfo a {
                text-decoration: none;
                color: #999;
                font-size: 0.8em;
            }
            .siteinfo a:hover {
                color: #602F8D;
                text-decoration: underline;
            }
```

}

Comment: You need to add style for selector: `.shell > img {float: right;}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class "tagline" has "position:relative; left: 505px" and it's a problem. Just remove "left: 505px" and add class "text-right" to the div.